# Highcharts | Label width control in bar charts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to find a way to control width of the x-axis labels container in bar charts in styled mode. I want to have preset values and depending on the preset have labels to take 20, 30, 40, 50% of the graphic. Is there a property for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set labels' width depending on their length and relative to chart width, you can use `chart.event.render` to achieve that. It will allow you to find the number of characters and set dynamically the percentage width.

```
var allowChartUpdate = true;

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    styledMode: true,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        if (allowChartUpdate) {
          this.xAxis[0].categories.forEach(category => {
            if (category.length > 10) {
              var dynamicMargin = this.chartWidth * 50 / 100;
              allowChartUpdate = false;

              this.update({
                chart: {
                  marginLeft: dynamicMargin
                }
              }, true, true, false);

              allowChartUpdate = true;
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/59xjq4du/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render